# Java: How to get the parts of a path

Tags: java, algorithm, filepath

This should be fairly simple, but I'm just stuck. Say you have the path `/a/b/c/`. I'd like to convert that into an array containing:

- `/`
- `/a/`
- `/a/b/`
- `/a/b/c/`

The slash at the beginning and the end should be optional. Any one care to help?

I'm going to use it for a function that creates a directory, and I want it to create all the missing parts too and not fail if for example `a` or `b` doesn't exist.

---

**Update:** I would of course use `File.mkdirs()` if I could, but this isn't on the local file system. It's to simplify interfacing with an SFTP library which only has a `mkdir` method taking a path in the form of a string.

Comment: As both answers below cover, `File.mkdirs()` is the way forward. However, if you really insisted on doing it by hand a `split("//");` would give you the pieces, and you could just do a for loop: `String[] bits = path.split("//"); File f = null; for(int i=0;i<bits.length;i++){ if(f = null) f = new File(bit[i]); else f = new File(f, bits[i]); f.mkdir(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up with this code:

```
   public String[] componizePath(String path)
   {
      ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();  

      int index = 0;
      while(index < path.length())
      {
         if(path.charAt(index) == '/' || index == path.length()-1)
         {
            parts.add(path.substring(0, index+1));
         }
         index++;
      }

      return parts.toArray(new String[0]);
   }
```

---

**JUnit tests:**

```
   @Test
   public void componizePath_EmptyPath()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("");
      String[] expected = new String[0];
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_RootPath()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("/");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"/"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_SimplePath()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("a");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"a"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_SimplePathWithTrailingSlash()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("a/");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"a/"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_ComplexerPath()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("a/b/cc");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"a/", "a/b/", "a/b/cc"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_ComplexerPathWithTrailingSlash()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("a/b/c/");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"a/", "a/b/", "a/b/c/"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test
   public void componizePath_ComplexerPathWithLeadingSlash()
   {
      String[] actual = getSftp().componizePath("/a/b/c");
      String[] expected = new String[] {"/", "/a/", "/a/b/", "/a/b/c"};
      assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
   }
```

Answer (score 11):

Why not just use [`File.mkdirs()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)?

---

edit: per your requirement not to use File.mkdirs():

I still think it's easier to use `File` as a helper class:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileSplitter {
    final private File path;

    public List<String> getPathStrings()
    {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        File p = this.path;
        while (p != null)
        {
            list.addFirst(p.getPath());
            p = p.getParentFile();
        }
        return list;
    }

    public FileSplitter(File path) { this.path = path; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doit(new File("/foo/bar/baz"));
        doit(new File("/bam/biff/boom/pow"));
    }

    private static void doit(File file) {
        for (String s : new FileSplitter(file)
                .getPathStrings())
            System.out.println(s);      
    }
}
```

On my machine (windows) this prints out:

```
\
\foo
\foo\bar
\foo\bar\baz
\
\bam
\bam\biff
\bam\biff\boom
\bam\biff\boom\pow
```

If you have a need to use forward slashes no matter what, then I'd either implement using strings rather than Files, or just do a `.replace('\\','/')` on point of use.

---

Finally, here's an approach that might be more helpful for your end application.

It has the same output as the previous, but lends itself to an inversion of control
where you can perform your custom `mkdir()` as a pseudo-Runnable to be passed in as a step to a path iterator:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;

public class PathRunner
{
    final private File path;
    public PathRunner(File path) { 
        this.path = path; 
    }

    public interface Step
    {
        public boolean step(File path);
    }

    public boolean run(Step step) 
    {
        return run(step, this.path);
    }
    private boolean run(Step step, File p)
    {
        if (p == null)
            return true;
        else if (!run(step, p.getParentFile()))
            return false;
        else
            return step.step(p);
    }

    /**** test methods ****/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doit(new File("/foo/bar/baz"));
        doit(new File("/bam/biff/boom/pow"));
    }
    private static boolean doit(File path) {
        Step step = new Step()
        {
            @Override public boolean step(File path) {
                System.out.println(path);
                return true;
                /* in a mkdir operation, here's where you would call: 

                return yourObject.mkdir(
                    path.getPath().replace('\\', '/')
                );
                 */
            }               
        };
        return new PathRunner(path).run(step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added to the answer why I cannot use that. Should've mentioned that in the first place, my bad :9

Comment: Sort of got this to work. It messes up the slashes though, which is not so good.

Comment: partially. Just don't trust it will keep the potential beginning and end slash. Also don't really want to do that if I can avoid it :)

Answer (score 5):

### If you need something primitive. Try split and append.

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] folders = "/a/b/c/".split("/");
        String[] paths = new String[folders.length];
        String path = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
            path +=   folders[i] + "/";
            paths[i] = path;
        }
    }
}
```

### This the output of code block:

```
run:
/
/a/
/a/b/
/a/b/c/
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Simple and seems to work. What if there are no `/` at the beginning or at the end though? From what I can see it will add a slash at the end even if it wasn't any.

Comment: @Svish you are right about corner cases but this code is just a proof of concept to give you the idea. you can improve it for corner cases or just force user to input a path with leading and trailing slash.

Answer (score 4):

The File class supports this.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    split(new File("/a/b/c/d/e"));
    split(new File("\\A\\B\\C\\D\\E"));
}

private static void split(File file) {
    File parent = file.getParentFile();
    if (parent != null) split(parent);
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

on windows prints

```
\
\a
\a\b
\a\b\c
\a\b\c\d
\a\b\c\d\e
\
\A
\A\B
\A\B\C
\A\B\C\D
\A\B\C\D\E
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to do this.  [File.mkdirs() instead](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

this should be a fairly simple algorithm, if your are given a string path = "/a/b/c/", you can do the following:

```
def f(st):
    index = 0
    array = []
    while index < len(st):
        if(st[index] == '/'):
            array += [st[:index+1]]

        index += 1
    return array
```

This is a python algorithm, you can easily convert that to Java. Of course you can use the File.mkdirs() that Jason and I82Much pointed out, but its also fun to see how the algorithm works.

**EDIT**
In the case of Java, you cannot iterate over a string, but you can covert the String into an arraylist of charachters, and when you iterate , you write the condition that if the charachter is '/', then create a new string that concatenates all the characters from the first till the current one we found which should be a '/', and add it to a String list you initialized earlier. The resulting string list will be the list you need.
It is good practice for you if you try it on your own and see how it goes. And of course you can iterate over the resulting list and make directories.

Comment: What does `array += [st[:index+1]]` do? I assume it adds another element to the array, but with what exactly?

Comment: @Svish: st[:index + 1] is a python syntax that is the string from 0 to index, for example if st = "abcdef", then st[:3]= "abc" . hope that helps